# unfortunately GeoQuiz has stopped working in bignerdranch

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try to run my app on the emulator I have a tab message saying

> "unfortunately,GeoQuiz has stopped working" .......

GeoQuiz is my app's name .......
here is my activity class in the QuizActivity.java file

```
public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button mTrueButton;

private Button mFalseButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mTrueButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mFalseButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quiz, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I have no images at all in my app 
and the min sdk version for this app is API 16:android 4.1 (jelly bean)
and the targeted version is API 21:android 5.0 (Lollipop)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.  I havel also marked down you r error message using '>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont call `setContentView` at the right place:
you call it at the end of the `onCreate` method! You have to move these two lines to the beginning of the `onCreate` Method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
```

because of that you get a `NullPointerException` here:

```
 mTrueButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
 mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // NPE
```